# Parsing stdin in C causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c, stdin

I keep hitting a segmentation fault when calling anything that reads from stdin. I have no idea why. Calling `getchar()` or any other similar function from within a certain function causes my program to crash, but when I call it from another function, it works fine. Here's the part that crashes:

```
int prompt()
{
  int i;
  int selection = -1;
  while (selection < 0 || selection > 9) {
    printf("Item:\n\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
      printf("%d) %s\n", i, getItemName(i));
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
      printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Select the number of the corresponding item: ");
    char input = getchar(); <--- dies here!
    if (input != EOF && input != '\n') flush();
    selection = atoi(input); <--- error here!
  } 

  return selection;
}

void flush() {
    char c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        c = getchar();
}
```

**UPDATE** After a lot of exprimenting, I found out that the issue was with the code I marked out. (the `atoi()`). I was passing it a simple `char`, rather than a `char*`. I still don't get why when I used a bunch of `printfs`, it would die at the line I specified, and not before the call to `atoi()`.

Comment: What compiler are you using, is this code in a different file, do you have the same headers, are you getting any warnings from the linker... etc.

Comment: I did something kind-of similar, cause I used a bunch of printfs to track the code. I haven't learned gdb yet. Just revisiting C to help a friend.

Comment: I do not see how this would cause the crash, but: In both `prompt` and `flush`, the source code assigns the result of `getchar()` to a char object. Then it compares that object to EOF. However, EOF is an int with a value different from any char, so the comparison always indicates unequal. This causes `prompt` to call `flush` and causes `flush` to loop forever. The return type of `getchar()` is an int, and it should be assigned to an int until after it is tested to ensure it is not EOF. Once you are sure it is not EOF, you may convert it to a char.

Comment: atoi expects a null terminated string, you are giving is a char (not even a char *). this doesnt compile

Comment: @Gir Problem is that it DID compile without warning, and then continued to run, crashing at the marked line, `getchar`, rather than the erroneous line, `atoi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile and run it with a debugger, you will find that the problem is actually in your `atoi` call.

```
char input = ...;
...
selection = atoi(input);
```

`atoi` takes a `char *`, so you are telling it to convert the string at address `0x00000030` (for `'0'`) to a number, and that is an invalid address.

in gdb:

```
Select the number of the corresponding item: 0

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000030
0x00007fff8ab00c53 in strtol_l ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff8ab00c53 in strtol_l ()
#1  0x0000000100000dc5 in prompt () at test.c:45
#2  0x0000000100000cb9 in main () at test.c:21
```

Compiling with warnings would also have told you this:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 test.c
test.c: In function ‘prompt’:
test.c:48: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```